# How do I pass a column as a parameter in Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, dynamic-sql

How do I pass and use the column name to retrieve a bigint variable in the actual column?

```
DECLARE @personID BIGINT,
DECLARE @queryString varchar(500)

Set @queryString = 'Select @personID = ' + @PersonColumnID + ' from dbo.Loss_Witness where WitnessID = @witnessID'
exec(@queryString)
```

Error message states "Must declare variable '@personID'."  I also tried

```
Set @queryString = 'Select ' + @personID + ' = ' + @witnessPersonID + ' from dbo.Loss_Witness where WitnessID = @witnessID'
```

And got the error message "Error converting data type varchar to bigint."

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify that @personID is an out parameter with the `OUTPUT` keyword:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(max)
    SET @SQL = 'SELECT @personID = w.' + @PersonColumnID + ' 
                  FROM dbo.Loss_Witness w
                 WHERE w.witnessID = @witnessID '

BEGIN 

  EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, @personID = @personID OUTPUT, @witnessID

END
```

There's [another example here](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#sp_executesql).

Answer (score 1):

Also note that there is potentially an SQL Injection security hole in your code. If you're not sanitizing @PersonColumnID then you could be in big trouble.

Comment: @OMG Ponies There is still a risk here, even if slight: column names can not be passed as parameters to sp_executesql and thus the reason for the concatenation in the input (but note that the values are parametrized).

Comment: I'm struggling to understand this comment. The paper you cite is excellent, and a standard read on dynamic SQL. But regardless of that, there is a huge SQL Injection point in the code given and in your rewrite, unless @PersonColumnID is sanitized. It was possible that the questioner wasn't aware of this.

Comment: SELECT @PersonColumnID = '1; drop database blah --' ;